# executing if-statement from command prompt

Tags: bash, command-line, sudo, prompt

In bash I can do the following:

```
if [ -f /tmp/test.txt ]; then echo "true"; fi
```

However, if I add `sudo` in front, it doesn't work anymore:

```
sudo if [ -f /tmp/test.txt ]; then echo "true"; fi
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: See [this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641233/how-do-i-sudo-if-in-bash)...

Comment: It is better practice to `sudo` only the `test` and/or only the `echo`. Not the entire `if` statement.

Comment: You mean `if sudo test`? Yes, that'd be better. I can't use `test` without the `if`, because it sets the exit code otherwise.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`sudo` executes its argument using `exec`, not via a shell interpreter. Therefore, it is limited to actual binary programs and cannot use shell functions, aliases, or builtins (`if` is a builtin). Note that the `-i` and `-s` options  can be used to execute the given commands in a login or non-login shell, respectively (or just the shell, interactively; note that you'll have to escape the semicolons or quote the command).

```
$ sudo if [ -n x ]; then echo y; fi
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
$ sudo if [ -n x ]\; then echo y\; fi
sudo: if: command not found
$ sudo -i if [ -n x ]\; then echo y\; fi
y
$ sudo -s 'if [ -n x ]; then echo y; fi'
y
```

Comment: So, if I use `-i` or `-s`, the if-statement will be evaluated properly?

Comment: Yes, so long as it's quoted or escaped properly. See my edit.

Answer (score 16):

Try calling the line as a string argument through the shell.

```
sudo /bin/sh -c 'if [ -f /tmp/test.txt ]; then echo "true"; fi'
```

Comment: this helped me debug!